# When is a function a permutation of the integers?

Tags: functions, permutations, collatz-conjecture

> When is a function a permutation of the integers?

In his 2011 paper on the Collatz conjecture [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309224.pdf) Lagarias writes;

```
> Collatz’s  original  function, which is a permutation of the integers...
```

But when is a function over the integers a permutation of the integers?  My understanding would be that a permutation must be a bijection from a domain onto itself because only this will reposition every domain element uniquely in the range.

But if we consider the Collatz function exactly a sixth of the integers are mapped to by two distinct elements; namely every even number equivalent to $1\mod 3$, which is is mapped to by both $3x+1$ and $x/2$ e.g.the number 16.

This doesn't seem to be a permutation because $16$ and other numbers will appear multiple times in the range.

Where am I (or Lagarias) going wrong?  If it's his mistake, what do you suppose he meant by this?

Comment: Lagarias explains this on page 37; the *original function* of Collatz is a permutation of integers. It is **not** the function we are considering nowadays.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks. Did you know of this apparent discrepancy already?

Comment: No, I did not, but I suspected that the answer can be found in Lagarias paper. He is very reliable. And indeed, I found it quickly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Collatz *original function* was defined as follows:
Consider the infinite permutation
$$
P ={1 2 3 4 5 6 \cdots \choose 1 3 2 5 7 4 \cdots}
$$
taking $n\to f(n)$ where $f : \mathbb{N}^+ \mapsto \mathbb{N}^+$ is given by 
$$f(3n) = 2n, f(3n−1) = 4n−1, f(3n−2) =4n − 3.$$
This is *different* from the Collatz function defined in the $3n+1$-problem!

Reference: Jeffrey C. Lagarias: [The $3x + 1$ Problem: An Annotated Bibliography (1963–1999)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309224.pdf); page 37.

Edit: A permutation of a set $X$ is an element of the group ${\rm Sym}(X)$ consisting of all bijective maps from $X$ to $X$. If $|X|=n$, then ${\rm Sym}(X)\cong S_n$, the symmetric group.

Comment: thanks. I wasn't so confident in my own understanding of a permutation. If you add to your question confirmation of when a function is a permutation I can accept it.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A006369 seems to be the sequence

Comment: I find it a bit more intuitive to write $f(3n) = 2n, f(3n−1) = 4n−1, f(3n+1) =4n+1 $ (but that's subjective, of course)